# Django queryset search on multiple models, return the same object

Tags: django, search, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to create an advanced search on my website, you are looking at various models related to each one, always returning a list of profiles that meet some parameters

Here are my Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)
    residence=models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    birthdate=models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    telephone=models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    linkedin=models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    starred=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_from = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser,  related_name='profile_author')
    created_on = models.DateField(default=tznow)
    internal_id = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)

class Education(models.Model):
    almalaurea_id = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='education_profile')
    education_type = models.ForeignKey(Education_type, related_name='education_type')

class Education_type(models.Model):
    VALUES = (
        (0, 'Altro'),
        (1, 'Licenza media'),
        (2, 'Diploma'),
        (3, 'Laurea Triennale'),
        (4, 'Laurea Magistrale'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    value = models.IntegerField(choices=VALUES)
```

I want to search the profiles that meet various results, such as `birthdate`, `residence`, `starred`, `education` (based on `education_type`)
This is an example scenario, my research includes other models

These are the research in my view, I thought that having found the results of the two queries, I could extract the profile id and compare them, then run another query by selecting profiles that match, but I think it's not a great idea, the real scenario includes other various models.

```
    filters_profile = []
    filters_education = []

    year = form.cleaned_data["year"]
    residence = form.cleaned_data["residence"]
    starred = form.cleaned_data["starred"]
    education_type = form.cleaned_data["education_type"]

    if year:
        filters_profile.append(Q(birthdate__year=year))

    if residence:
        filters_profile.append(Q(residence__icontains=residence))

    if starred:
        filters_profile.append(Q(starred=starred))

    result_profile = Profile.objects.filter(reduce(lambda q1, q2:  q1 & q2, filters_profile)).order_by('first_name')

    result_education = None
    if education_type:
        e = Education_type.objects.filter(title=education_type)
        result_education = Education.objects.filter(education_type=e).prefetch_related('profile','education_type')
```

Any idea?
Many thanks in advance :)

EDIT :

About the solution of @Geo Jacob
Here is the third models:

```
    if valutation:
        result_valutation = Status.objects.filter(valutation=valutation).values_list('profile_id', flat=True)
            key['id__in'] = result_valutation
```

Adding this code for my scenario, this solution don't work, as i written in the comments :)

```
"in practice, the content of key['id__in'] is overwritten when the other model query (this) is executed"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
key = {}
year = form.cleaned_data["year"]
residence = form.cleaned_data["residence"]
starred = form.cleaned_data["starred"]
education_type = form.cleaned_data["education_type"]

if year:
    key['birthdate__year'] = year

if residence:
    key['residence__icontains'] = residence

if starred:
    key['starred'] = starred

if education_type:
    e = Education_type.objects.filter(title=education_type)
    result_education = Education.objects.filter(education_type=e).values_list('profile_id', flat=True)
    key['id__in'] = result_education

result_profile = Profile.objects.filter(**key).order_by('first_name')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, seems to be a good solution, the problem is that adding a third model does not work You will also find profiles with a new parameter "valutation" from a third model without cosiderare "education"

Comment: any idea to resolve this problem? in practice, the content of key['id__in']  is overwritten when the other model query is executed , I should queue the new result objects, how?

Answer (score 0):

My solution working on more than 2 models, based on @Geo Jacob solution, thank you

I make a check and put in `key['id__in']` only matched id from the previous query, so as to intersect the results

```
            key = {}
            statokey = 0

            year = form.cleaned_data["year"]
            residence = form.cleaned_data["residence"]
            starred = form.cleaned_data["starred"]
            education_type = form.cleaned_data["education_type"]
            valutation = form.cleaned_data["valutation"]

            if year:
                key['birthdate__year'] = year

            if residence:
                key['residence__icontains'] = residence

            if starred:
                key['starred'] = starred

            if education_type:
                e = Education_type.objects.filter(title=education_type)
                result_education = Education.objects.filter(education_type=e).values_list('profile_id', flat=True)
                if statokey > 0:
                    for r in result_education:
                        for k in key['id__in']:
                            if r == k:
                                key['id__in'] = str(r)

                else:
                    key['id__in'] = result_education
                    statokey += 1

            if valutation:
                result_valutation = Status.objects.filter(valutation=valutation).values_list('profile_id', flat=True)
                if statokey > 0:
                    for r in result_valutation:
                        for k in key['id__in']:
                            if r == k:
                                key['id__in'] = str(r)
                else:
                    key['id__in'] = result_valutation
                    statokey += 1


            result_profile = Profile.objects.filter(**key).order_by('first_name')
```